# SIlverlight 4, FilterDescriptor and GUID as FilterOperator

Tags: silverlight-4.0, filter, guid, ria, domaindatasource

Hey guys, as seen in [this](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/188076/431521.aspx) post, GUIDs are not supported by the FilterDescriptorts FilterOperator. Has anyone encountered this problem? Is there a workaround? Because, well it pretty much sucks (no filtering by foreign keys and so on... which is quite common).

Answer (score 2):

Set the filter descriptor in code

```
public ClassName()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataSource.FilterDescriptors[0].Value = Guid.Empty;
}
```